# Get PDO lastInsertId() from table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is it possible to get `lastInsertId()` from a method, and also if possible get the value from a specific table?

The method I try to use is in my `db.class.php`

```
public function getLastID(){ 
 $dbh = $this->db_connect(); 
 if($dbh){ 
  try{
   $lastId = $dbh->lastInsertId(); 
   return $lastId; 
  } 
  catch(PDOException $err){
   return $err->getMessage(); 
  } 
 } 
 else{ 
  return false; 
 } 
}
```

When I access the method, `echo $db->getLastID();`, the value I get is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
return $db->lastInsertId('column');
```

OR

```
$db->getDbh()->lastInsertId();
```

stackoverflow.com/questions/10809752/how-to-use-pdolastinsertid

Comment: But I can not add this to a method and call it at anytime. It needs to be in the same connection if I understand correctly. I was thinking of a method which I could call at any given place.